# How can I match a list of strings to another list of strings?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I'm an undergraduate student learning R for the first time. I'm using the `tidyverse` package (specifically `stringr`) in RStudio to switch the first and last letters of strings in a Scrabble dataset and compare the new, switched-strings column to the original column to find matches. The dataset includes all playable Scrabble words. Essentially, I'm trying to find how many words are still valid, playable words after switching the first and last characters.

I have no problem finding exact matches (ex: `AHA` to `AHA` or `ABAYA` to `ABAYA`) but non-exact matches (ex: `REEL` to `LEER`) are showing up as `FALSE`.
Here is my code for exact matches:

```
scrabble5<-scrabble%>%
  mutate(backwards=str_replace(word, "^(.)(.*)(.)$", "\\3\\2\\1"))%>%
  mutate(match=backwards==word)
```

I assumed adding `any()` to the last line would work, so the code would read:

```
scrabble5<-scrabble%>%
  mutate(backwards=str_replace(word, "^(.)(.*)(.)$", "\\3\\2\\1"))%>%
  mutate(match=backwards==any(word))
```

However, when I try this, the `match` column does not print any `TRUE` values, only `FALSE`.

Ultimately, I would like to have my `match` column read `TRUE` for all matches, whether exact or not.

EDIT: I apologize if the above wording is confusing. My ideal end-point is to have a logical column with `TRUE` values when one of the switched strings (indicated by the new `backwards` column) matches any of the strings in the original column, `word`.

Comment: i think you are looking for the %in% operator. It checks if an element (like a word) is present in another object (like a vector of strings).

Comment: REEL != LEER, so it will return FALSE. What exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find a good duplicate (but I'm sure there's one out there).

The `%in%` function does what you want.

```
scrabble5<-scrabble %>%
  mutate(backwards = str_replace(word, "^(.)(.*)(.)$", "\\3\\2\\1")) %>%
  mutate(match = backwards %in% word)
```